# R - How do I create a variable that encompasses different intervals (elected office terms for several countries)?

Tags: r, intervals

I have a database with informations about elections in several countries across the globe. All of the countries from my database have elections, and all these elections happen the year before the elected official take office. Hence, a term always starts the year after the elections.

However, most countries have completely unique intervals between elections, which makes it hard to automatize the proccess. Country X might have elections from 4 to 4 years and Country Y might have them from 10 to 10. I made a fictional database for clarity purposes.

```
tab_elections <- data.frame(country = c('Country X', 'Country X', 'Country X', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country Y', 'Country Y'),
                            election = c('1996', '2000', '2004', '2008', '1990', '2000', '2010'))
```

I also have a yearly database for the same countries that does not have electoral information.

```
tab_country <- data.frame(country = c('Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y'),
                  year = c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011))
```

I want to merge the "Elections database" with the "Yearly database" creating a variable that informs me "when the current president was elected".

It should look like this:

```
tab <- data.frame(country = c('Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y', 'Country X', 'Country Y'),
                  year = c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2006, 2006, 2007, 2007, 2008, 2008, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011),
                  year_president_elected = c(1996, 1990, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2004, 2000, 2004, 2000, 2004, 2000, 2004, 2000, 2008, 2000, 2008, 2000, 2008, 2010))
```

I don't know if this is correct, but basically I'd like insight on how to merge both databases creating a variable that gets "the latest observation for each country without counting the year itself" (because the year the president is elected is not the year they start their term). If there is any R package that understands dates, it would be even better.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you can do is define the difference in election years in a mutate function `tab_elections %>% mutate(year_elected = ifelse(country == "Country X", as.numeric(election) + 2, as.numeric(election)))`and then left join the tables

Comment: Different countries have different intervals, and the list of countries is too big for me to know (their intervals also change with time and regime change)